# Best way to create index for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am having records stored in mongo-db collection for customer and there transactions with below format:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59b6992a0b54c9c4a5434088"), 
"Results" : {
    "id" : "2139623696", 
    "member_joined_date" : ISODate("2010-07-07T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "account_activation_date" : ISODate("2010-07-07T00:00:00.000+0000"),  
    "family_name" : "XYZ", 
    "given_name" : "KOKI HOI", 
    "gender" : "Female",
    "dob" : ISODate("1967-07-20T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "preflanguage" : "en-GB", 
    "title" : "MR", 
    "contact_no" : "60193551626", 
    "email" : "abc123@xmail.com", 
    "street1" : "address line 1", 
    "street2" : "address line 2", 
    "street3" : "address line 3", 
    "zipcd" : "123456", 
    "city" : "xyz", 
    "countrycd" : "Malaysia", 
    "Transaction" : [
        {
            "txncd" : "411", 
            "txndate" : ISODate("2017-08-02 00:00:00.000000"), 
            "prcs_date" : ISODate("2017-08-02 00:00:00.000000"), 
            "txn_descp" : "Some MALL : SHOP & FLY FREE", 
            "merchant_id" : "6587867dsfd", 
            "orig_pts" : "0.00000", 
            "text" : "Some text"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create index on fields "txn_descp", "txndate", "member_joined_date", "gender", "dob" for faster access. Can some one help me in creating index for this document? Will appreciate any kind of help and suggestions.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+how+to+add+index

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the index there are a few things to keep in mind.

- Always create the index for the queries you use.
- Go for compound indexes whenever possible.
- First field in the index should be the one with the minimum possible values.Ie, if there is an index with gender and DOB as keys, It is better to have {gender:1,dob:1}

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am just wondering my transaction related fields are hierarchically inside  ( Results -> Transaction -> txndate ). Will that effect while query?

Comment: It will affect the size of the index and in turn affect the memory usage. The key will be "Transaction. txndate" which will take more space to store. It's always better to go for medium size field names and keep the index field at root level. But, hierarchical structure also has advantages.